# Not able to install latest version of scikit-learn

Tags: linux, debian, python, upgrade, pip

I am working on Debian Stable Linux with Python version 3.7.3 which is otherwise working very well. I have scikit-learn (sklearn) version 0.22.2 installed and I want to upgrade it to [latest version 0.23](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html)

I am using following commands but they are not working:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user scikit-learn 
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.22.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.4.1)


$ python3 -m pip install --user sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sklearn) (0.22.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn) (1.18.1)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Note: `pip` is also upgraded to the latest version.

As pointed out in comments, output of `pip show` command:

```
$ python3 -m pip show scikit-learn
Name: scikit-learn
Version: 0.22.2
Summary: A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining
Home-page: http://scikit-learn.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: new BSD
Location: /home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: joblib, scipy, numpy
Required-by: yellowbrick, tsfresh, sklearn, pingouin, MindsDB, lightwood
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`--upgrade` (`-U`) option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u)? That is, something like `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user scikit-learn` and `python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user sklearn`?

Comment: This actually worked! I thought `install` option will check version and upgrade but it does not. If you enter this as an answer I will accept it. Users also tend to skip reading comments.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I have added an answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using following commands but they are not working:
>
> ```
> $ python3 -m pip install --user scikit-learn
> [...]
> $ python3 -m pip install --user sklearn
> ```

When updating an existing, installed Python package with `pip install`, you should typically include the [--upgrade (-U)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u) option e.g.:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user scikit-learn

python3 -m pip install --upgrade --user sklearn
```

This option automates the process of uninstalling the prior version of the package and then collects and installs the most recent version available to `pip`.

Technically, you can also uninstall the package yourself with `pip uninstall` before using `pip install`, but using the `--upgrade` option saves a step.

---

*Depending on your needs, it is also possible to use the [--ignore-installed (-I)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-i) option (which simply ignores any installed packages and overwrites them). But this can break your system depending on the circumstances and shouldn't be used for general upgrades.*

---

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it from Debian packages archive.
Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-sklearn python3-sklearn-lib
```

Comment: Debian Stable repository has even older version: 0.20.2 !

Comment: May I know the version of Debian you are using?

Comment: The above answer worked perfectly on my Debian 10 Buster Stable machine.If you are using Debian 10, update you source list and try again.

Comment: Add the output from `python3 -m pip show scikit-learn` to your question.

Comment: Added. That also shows same version information.

Comment: If you use Debian 10, I might share my source list with you if you don't mind.
I suggest you should update your source list and try again.

Comment: Please post it in your answer above.

Comment: I already have `buster main contrib` in my sources.list

Comment: Download a **whl** file of the latest release and install it manually.